# I can't export scraped data in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv, beautifulsoup

I can't get all data in CSV, only last. When scraping is done only last one scraped is saving CSV file but I want to save from all pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
mainurl = 'https://austin.craigslist.org/search/cta?s=0'
driver.get(mainurl)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

lnk_opener = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li[1]/p/a').click()
time.sleep(4)
records = []
i = 1
while i <3:
    i+=1

    try:
        print(driver.current_url)
    except Exception:
        print('Internet Error Detected')

    try:
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="titletextonly"]').text
        print(title)
    except Exception:
        print('No Title Given')
    try:
        price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section/h2/span/span[2]').text
        print(price)
    except Exception:
        print('No Price Given')
    try:
        phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="postingbody"]/h2[1]/big').text
        print(phone)
        records.append((phone))
    except Exception:
        print('No Mobile number avalible')
    try:
        loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section/section/div[1]/div/div[2]').text
        print(loc)
    except Exception:
        print('No Location Data Avalible')
    try:
        img = page_soup.find('img')
        immg = print(img.get('src','\n'))
    except Exception:
        print('No img Found')

    nxtpg = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section/header/div[1]/div/a[3]')
    nxtpg.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/section/header/div[1]/div/a[3]").get_attribute("href")
    if url == None:
        bckbtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('backup').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        nextbuttton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]/a[3]').click()
        time.sleep(6)
        print(records)

records.append((driver.current_url, title, price, loc, immg))
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Product Url', 'Title/Model/Make', 'Price', 'GM Location', 'Image Link'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('zzz.csv')
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line

```
records.append((driver.current_url, title, price, loc, immg))
```

should be inside the `while` statement. Also, move `i += 1` to the end of the statement, otherwise you're skipping the first iteration.

Comment: Now i have new error like "loc is not defined, or phone", why only this names are not defined?